# Understanding a step in the proof of a proposition required for defining orientation of manifolds via homology generators.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

Here is the proposition and its proof:

> [image]

But I do not understand:

1-how the second line from below is by long exact sequence. Could anyone explain this to me, please?

2- Also, did we use excision 2 times? In the first and second line.

Comment: I think, that's just the long exact sequence for relative homology. In this case $\mathbb{R}^n - x$ is homotopy equivalent to a point. And relative homology w.r.t to a point, coincides with reduced homology.

Comment: @RohanNuckchady could you please tell me at which pg. in AT is this information? Also I edited my question with another question, could you please look at it?

Comment: It's example $2.18$ on page $118$. I'm not sure if it's explained enough, but it comes from $\empty \rightarrow \star \rightarrow X$ and the corresponding long exact sequence ( here the arrows mean inclusion )

Comment: What is $\empty$? @RohanNuckchady

Comment: meant empty set

Comment: @RohanNuckchady what about my other question?

Comment: For excision use $(M-U)$ then $M-(M-U) = U$ and $(M - \{ x\}) - (M - U) = U - \{x\}$

Comment: Do you know the long exact sequence for reduced homology groups?

Comment: I understood the answer to my first question from Rohan . thanks @PaulFrost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We only use excision once, in the first line, as Osama Ghani points out: we can excise $M \setminus U$ from the pair $(M,M\setminus \{x\})$ and since

$$
M \setminus (M \setminus U) = U
$$

and

$$
(M \setminus \{x\}) \setminus (M \setminus U) = U \setminus \{x\}
$$

then $H_\bullet(M,M\setminus \{x\}) \simeq H_\bullet(U,U\setminus \{x\})$.

The fact that $H_\bullet(U,U \setminus \{x\}) \simeq H_\bullet(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R}^n\setminus \{x'\})$ comes from the fact that the given chart induces a homeo $U  \to \mathbb{R}^n$ which sends $U$ minus a point to euclidean space without a point (writing both of these with the same name is just abuse of notation).

Now, we lave a long exact sequence

$$\cdots \to H_k(\mathbb{R}^n \setminus \{x'\}) \to H_k(\mathbb{R}^n) \to H_k(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R}^n\setminus \{x'\}) \to H_{k-1}(\mathbb{R}^n \setminus \{x'\})\to H_{k-1}(\mathbb{R}^n) \to\cdots
$$

Since $\mathbb{R}^n$ is contractible, its homology in positive degrees vanishes, and thus

$$
H_k(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R}^n\setminus \{x'\}) \simeq H_{k-1}(\mathbb{R}^n \setminus \{x'\}) \simeq \widetilde{H}_{k-1}(\mathbb{R}^n \setminus \{x'\})
$$

for $k \geq 2$. In low degrees, the sequence is

$$
0 \to H_1(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R}^n\setminus \{x'\}) \to H_0(\mathbb{R}^n \setminus \{x'\})\to H_0(\mathbb{R}^n) \to H_0(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R}^n\setminus \{x'\}) \to 0.
$$

and $H_0(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R}^n\setminus \{x'\}) = 0$ since $\mathbb{R}^n$ is path-connected.

The map between $H_0(\mathbb{R}^n \setminus \{x'\})\to H_0(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is then an epi between infinite cyclic groups, and so it must be an iso, which shows that

$$
H_1(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R}^n\setminus \{x'\})  = 0 = \widetilde{H}_0(\mathbb{R}^n \setminus \{x'\}). 
$$

Finally, we use that $\mathbb{R}^n \setminus \{x'\}$ is homotopy equivalent to a $(n-1)$-sphere, whose homology we know beforehand.